# Failure to open filename stored in string C++

Tags: c++, file-io, concatenation

I have a code that reads a file name `xxx` from `commands.in` and stores it in a string, well call it `string name`.

I want to open `xxx` since it's a file as well, so I concatenate `.data` to the end of it (since all my files end with `.data`) so it can be opened like so.

`string filename = name + ".data";`

Now I ouput that string to the console and it reads `xxx.data`, so I know it concatenated correctly. When I try to open a file using the string however, I keep getting my error message "file does not exist". This is what I'm doing :

`fstream fileObj;`

`fileObj.open(filename.c_str());`(which is `xxx.data`)This is saying the file doesn't exist. When I open the file by it's actual name `fileObj.open("xxx.data");` it finds the file no problem and does the operations I want. The string that I'm putting into the `.open` argument is the exact same as actually typing it in, but it's not working. Any Idea why this might be?

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
//#include "Cache.h"

using namespace std;



double Avg(string fileName);
int Min(string fileName);
int Max(string filename);
int Med(string filename);




int main(){

  int numFile;
  string fileName;
  string opName;
  fstream fileObj;
  double avgVal;
  cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" << endl;
  fileObj.open("commands.in");

  fileObj >> numFile;


  for (int i = 0; i < numFile; i++){
    fileObj >> fileName;
    fileObj >> opName;



    if (opName == "Avg")
      {
        cout << "\n\nFilename = " << fileName<<endl;
        cout << "going for avg here"<<endl;
        avgVal = Avg(fileName);
        cout << avgVal;

  }

  return 0;
}

double Avg(string filename)
{
  cout << "ENTERED AVG METHOD" << endl;
  fstream file;
  string name = filename + ".data";
  // file.open(filename.c_str());
  file.open("A.data");
  if (file.fail())
    {
      cout << "The file was not found" << endl;
      return 0;
    }
  int count = 0;
  double allNum = 0;
  double current;
  double result;
  cout << "\nFilename goes here : " << name << endl;
  while(file)
    {
      file >> current;
      allNum += current;
      count +=1;
    }
  cout << "\n\n COUNT SHOULD BE 6 :  " << count << endl;

  result = allNum / count-1;

  return result;
}
```

`commands.in`

```
6
A Avg
B Max
C Med
A2 Avg
B Max
ABC Min
```

`A.data`

```
20
20
30
30
40
40
```

Comment: can you printf your `name` just before you try to open the file just to make sure?..

Comment: I have printed the name before, and it's the exact same. If the name of the file is `xxx.data` I print that as well as the concatenation and they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

- Did you forget to use your `filename` instead of `name`?
- Did you check that your `name` has a trailing new-line character?

Log it quoted to ensure that you try to open correct file:

```
printf("filename: '%s'\n", filename.c_str());
```

---

This code doesn't look ok:

```
  string name = filename + ".data";
  // file.open(filename.c_str());
  file.open("A.data");
```

Your `commands.in` has A.data and you append `.data` and then you still use `filename` and not `name`. Quite confusing. Change it all to this:

```
  cout << "Open file: ==>\"" << name << "\"<==\n";
  file.open(name.c_str());
```

Comment: The names used here are arbitrary. Let me doublecheck what I wrote is what I mean..

Comment: tell you what, I'll just load the code. give me a sec have to transfer from a Linux vm server

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure the file you're working with resides in the same directory as your current working directory. You might want to provide `fileObj.open(filename.c_str());` with an absolute path such as:

`string filename = "C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\filename.data"`

If the file does not exists in the same directory as your current working directory and you're not providing the fully qualified path, that error will keep popping up.

Also, try hard-coding the filename in to be sure there aren't any line terminators in the string:

`fileObj.open("C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\filename.data");`

Comment: Its a Linux machine, but yeah they are absolutely in the same directory. That's why typing it in works correctly but passing as a string doesn't.

Comment: @JeffreyDilley It shouldn't matter where the name comes from, they're interpreted the same way. And it's not relative to the directory of the executable, it's relative to your current working directory.

Comment: @Barmar I understand that. I'm positive directory isn't the issue though :/

Comment: @Jon how would I provide my filename.c_str() with an absolute path given that I would just have to use c_str again to replace "filename.data".?

Comment: To test it, just set the filename to a known file location such as `string filename = "~\filepath\filename.data"` and that will tell you if it's a location issue

Comment: I should have added, that if you want to do this on-the-fly, in linux you'd use `char *getwd(char *buf);` and make sure to `#include <unistd.h>`

Comment: @Jon In Linux it's `/`